# How data transfer between two html page

Tags: c#, cookies

I am trying to display hyperlinks in one page and when user click on link, page is navigate, but I want to fetch the name of hyperlink and show as label in different web page. Here I am trying with cookie, but cookie takes only last values of database is possible to store all the values in cookie?? thanks

```
 String sql1 = "select title,song_id from up_song where Song_type='Indian Pop Album'";
    adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, cn);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adpt.Fill(ds, "title1");
    var last6Uploaded1 = ds.Tables["title1"]
                              .AsEnumerable()
                              .OrderByDescending(r=> r.Field<int>("song_id"))
                              .Take(2);
    foreach (DataRow row in last6Uploaded1)
    {

        int songID = row.Field<int>("song_id");
        // you don't need the array of hyperlinks neither
        HyperLink hl = new HyperLink(); 
        hl.ID = "hyperlink" + songID;
        string title = row.Field<string>("title");
        hl.Text = title;
        hl.NavigateUrl = "Downloadpage.aspx";
        hl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        HttpCookie coo = new HttpCookie("song");
        coo["sogtit"] = title;
        Response.Cookies.Add(coo);
        Panel2.Controls.Add(hl);
        Panel2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can store multiple values, here is how you can do it:

```
string title = row.Field<string>("title");
string song_id = row.Field<int>("song_id").ToString();

HttpCookie coo = new HttpCookie("song");
cookie.Values.Add("songtit", title);
cookie.Values.Add("song_id", song_id);
```

You would retrieve the values in a destination page like this:

```
string title = response.Cookies["song"]["songtit"];
string song_id = response.Cookies["song"]["song_id"];
```

Another common way to pass data between web pages is through request parameters that are fetched from `QueryString` in the destination page. Set your URL like this :

```
hl.NavigateUrl = "Downloadpage.aspx?name=" + title;
```

in the `Downloadpage.aspx` in it's `Page_Load` event handler set:

```
yourLabel.Text = Request.QueryString["name"];
```

where `yourLabel` is a name of the label for which you want to set the text.

You can pass multiple parameters through request like this:

```
hl.NavigateUrl = "Downloadpage.aspx?name=" + title + "&otherParam=" + otherParam;
```

in destination page you can fetch the value of second parameter through `Request.QueryString["otherParam"]`.